# Razor helper intelligence not showing up on Orchard CMS

Tags: razor, orchardcms-1.6

I am not able to get Razor intellisense on the View in Orchard CMS? For example I need to get intellisense when I type @Html in VS 2012 for a Orchard CMS view in a module.
Let me knwo what I need to install or get Razor helpers working in my views ( cshtml)

Answer (score 0):

The project types for Orchard CMS Modules are not MVC projects. Instead, they are just C#, ASP.NET projects. Since intellisense is based on the Project Type (inside the .csproj file), you won't get Razor syntax within an Orchard module.

As for not using the MVC Project Type guid, this is by design, and there are no plans to add the Guid to Orchard to future or existing Orchard projects.

See https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19328 for more info.